# ReportBuilder 7.X and Delphi 7.X issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, report, reportbuilder

I have an issue with a report using ReportBuilder 7.X in an application built with Delphi 7.X.

The rights in the memo field are cut off when 'previewed' (see screenshot2.jpg), however you can see all of them when in the report designer (see screenshot.jpg).
 see screenshot3.jpg for the calc event code to the memo for filling the memo.

Why are these "rights" filling during preview incorrectly, but during design it displays correctly?

You can find all screenshots and a text file containing the code used in the calc OnPrint event for the memo field here:

http://www.adktripbuddy.com/misc/delphi/code/report/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is precise, and you did put all necessary information. Congratulations!

The "preview" pane of RB never works as expected for me, when data or layout are a bit complex (about SQL query, script code...). This is clearly a bug of RB. I never use this "preview" panel.

What about the "position" settings of the memo? Did you try changing it? Make it full height of the band?

What about the result in your application? If the report created in your app is correct, don't bother about preview in design mode.

Comment: Sorry, when i meant Preview, i mean preview mode in Designer, and running in report mode in my application,.  So, only in design mode i see it correctly. How do i change the position settings of the memo. Can i do this based on number of items in the memo?  - thanks for your help

Comment: You may try to expand the memo to your band height, then set the band height to the appropriate height.

Comment: Of course, that was like the first thing i did <smile>. The thing is, the number of items in the list grows depending on number of items in the database. Again though, this doesn't solve the issue as to why it works in design, but when viewing (previewing), it does not.

Comment: I guess i will assume your answer is correct and that it is a bug of RB for that version, since no one else has replied and stated otherwise. Thanks for responding!